# wait for result from an async method

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to call an async method from for loop, but it doesn't wait for the result from that method.

Below is my code:

```
async function fetchActivityHandler (req, reply) {
        esClient.search({
            index: 'user_activity',
            type: 'document',
            body: {
                _source : ["userId","appId","activity","createdAt","updatedAt"],
                query: {

                    bool : {
                        must:[
                        {match : { 'userId': req.params.id }}
                        ]
                    }

                }
            }
        },async function (error, response, status) {
            if (error){
                console.log('search error: '+error)
            }
            else {
                var activities = [];
                    //await Promise.all(response.hits.hits.map(async function(hit){
                    for (const hit of response.hits.hits) {
                        var activity = hit._source
                        var app = await fetchAppDetails(activity.appId);

                        console.log(app);
                        activity = {...activity,app : app}
                        activities.push(activity);
                        console.log(activity);
                }
                reply.status(200).send(activities);
            }
        });
    }

    async function fetchAppDetails (appId) {
        esClient.get({
            index: 'app',
            type: 'document',
            id: appId
        }, function (err, response) {
            console.log(response._source);
            return (response._source);
        });
    }
```

What may be the problem. I'm using async and await, but it is not working.

Comment: Uhhh, there's no `.forEach()` showing in your code.  Besides, `.forEach()` doesn't even pay attention to the return value form its callback so of course it won't wait for a returned promise (which is what an async function returns).  Can't do it that way.  Show us the actual code you're talking about or fix the description in your question.

Comment: i changed foreach to for loop. because it was not working for foreach

Comment: `fetchAppDetails()` doesn't return a promise.  `await` only waits for something if it's a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Await works with promise. You should wrap your function with promise to get this work. Hope this will help you. Also you do not need to use async on fetchActivityHandler  function. Only in the callback which you have already used.

```
function fetchAppDetails (appId) {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    esClient.get({
        index: 'app',
        type: 'document',
        id: appId
    }, function (err, response) {
        if(err){
            reject(err);
        }
        else{
            resolve(response)
        }

    });
  });   
 }
```